# Find application associated files

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I'm in the process of cleaning up my Mac files and want to uninstall some applications.

Some applications come with an uninstaller, others I can simply drag and drop to the trash. I'm aware that when you trash some applications, files are left behind via the library folder.

Is there a way to find all files associated to a particular application? I'd rather not install any third party software.

Comment: Have you already deleted the applications of which you speak? If no, wait until you get a good answer. You never know if you might need them. For example, if the application is running, you can use Activity Monitor > Sample Process to get the app's identifier which can help find support folders.

Comment: I know you said _"I'd rather not install any third party software."_ however I'm going to suggest this anyway because it's free and it works. [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) is the easiest way to go.

Comment: I haven't started deleting apps yet. I'll give Activity Monitor a go, thank you.